# Invalid formating for empty XML tags using XMLint

Tags: xml, linux, xmllint

I have a XML unformated document, like this one :

```
<foo>
<bar>
<hop>
<hey>
</hey>
</hop>
</bar>
</foo>
```

As you can see, the tag "hey" is empty. I remember that in this case, it should be written like `<hey/>`, but that's not a thing I can change.

To format this document, I use the `xmllint --format` command. But instead of outputing

```
<foo>
  <bar>
    <hop>
      <hey>
      </hey>
    </hop>
  </bar>
</foo>
```

or

```
<foo>
  <bar>
    <hop>
      <hey></hey>
    </hop>
  </bar>
</foo>
```

it outputs

```
<foo>
  <bar>
    <hop>
      <hey>
</hey>
    </hop>
  </bar>
</foo>
```

which is not what I want. I tried to write a sed command in order to indent these particular tags after xmllint work, but I couldn't prevent sed from loading the whole (huge) xml file, and it took several minutes, like more than xmllint.

The solution would be to find an option to ask xmllint to format these tag correctly, but I could not find it in the man. Do you know something that may help me please ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. Il'll delete this.

Comment: @jww is taking an incredibly narrow view of what constitutes "programming" and "development". I think the question is entirely on topic. Using utilities to reformat XML files is part of a developer's day job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hey` element isn't empty, it contains a single text node whose value is a newline character. Processes that reformat the XML will typically respect that, and leave the value of the element unchanged.

Comment: Down-voting an answer without saying why is just inconsiderate: if you think there's something wrong with the answer, please say why.

Comment: Well actually, I did not downvote this answer, and I think it will help me.